# Not able to access variable in google chrome console

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am using the latest version of `Meteor js`. I am a newbie and couldn't find the solution. I have surfed for this problem a lot.

Before going to the problem, please have look at the directory structure first.

My directory structure of the project is like this :

```
\client
    \main.html
    \main.css
    \main.js
\imports
    \lib
       \todos
           \todos.js
\server
    \main.js
```

I have created a `Mongo Object` in `todos.js`.

`export const Todos = new Mongo.Collections('todos');`

This is working fine.

Now in `client\main.js`, I am importing this object,

`import { Todos } from '\imports\lib\todos\todos.js';`

> Note: I tried relative and absolute both type of addressing.

I put a `debugger` after that and checked and the variable is there. I can access that variable on the console. But as soon as I pass the statement and all the code is rendered on the browser(google chrome), I am not able to use `Todos`. It is giving me a **ReferenceError**. The error is

> Todos is not defined.

I know there is no problem till the browser is loading because I checked that. I have surfed a lot. Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Edit 1: I am using windows 7 if that is necessary.

Comment: You are out of scope when the page is rendered. Modules are "lets say functions" with just inner scope, those import just passing in parameters and those are visible just inside of the function itself. You cant access those data outside unless you put them into something global ... like window object.

Comment: I saw other projects too. They were not using any window objects and I was able to get the data from the variable in console too. Do you know how can it be done without using window?

Comment: The only way I can think of it to bring the scope out through some variable or importing variables "into global scope" (use import + babel in index.js or something). Basic behaviour of the modules is that the imported variables are scoped and not accessible from console in global scope. There may be chrome plugins or some other "magic" to bring the scope out.

Comment: Hmmm is `Todo` "exported in `todos.js` ? Do you know what I mean ?  If it's not then it will be out of scope. Also, I'd use a relative addressing in the import statement `import { Todos } `../imports/...../todos.js`   Finally, edit your post ;  use `/` instead of `\` in your statements

Comment: @JasonKrs Thank you for the edit suggestion.
Yes, I exported `Todos` in `todos.js`. I mentioned that clearly in the question too. If that is not the correct way please tell me the correct way.

I have tried with both absolute and relative addressing both works same in case of meteor.

Comment: Sorry you actually did. I did not see that. Anyways did you import in both server and client `main.js` ?  Also, open your OS CLI and try to query `db.Todo.find({})` from meteor mongo of your project

Comment: Yes @JasonKrs, I did import it in both `server.js` and `client .js`. I did not mention anything about the `server.js` here is because in any case those two are mutually exclusive and cannot interfere with each other's file system and imports.

Comment: @JasonKrs, I did that too, the collection is being created. I can query it and add and delete objects from it.

Comment: Sorry I can't help with the details you've given. If it's really the `import` that is crashing, then you should check how it's implemented. Maybe you are hoisting something... Anyways, I'd suggest you drop that project and start again slowly step by step https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments above said, variables declared or imported in a file/module don't end up on the developers console.

What you can do to get stuff on the console is import it to the console using `require`

```
> require('/imports/lib/todos/todos.js')
```

Any valid absolute path or package will work here

> Note: the path separators are always *nix style `/`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem while trying to evaluate `moment` from Moment.js in Chrome console. It was imported by the script being debugged/under breakpoints but does not work in console. `import` or `require` Moment.js in console gave me errors and did not work for me.

I ended up switching to Firefox Developer Edition, where I can put breakpoints and then evaluate `moment` in its console out of the box without any problems.